# why WM_KEYDOWN not working when WM_COMMAND is triggered?

Tags: c++, user-interface, winapi

When i click the button in my client window then i pressed the down arrow key, the WM_KEYDOWN is not being sent to my windows procedure, but the other cases always works, so to solve this issue, I have to click outside of my client window and then then click in my client window (but not the button) then the WM_KEYDOWN will work, is there a better way to stop the focus of my button?

here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0501
#include <Windows.h>
#include <winuser.h>
#include <vector>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

const char* className = "MyCLASSNAME!";

HWND hButton;
RECT rect;
POINT p = {0, 0};

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{


    switch(msg)
    {
    case WM_CREATE:

        hButton = CreateWindow(TEXT("BUTTON"), TEXT("1"), WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD, 8, 41, 50, 50, hWnd, (HMENU)1, NULL, NULL);
        break;

    case WM_KEYDOWN:

        switch (wParam)
        {

        case VK_DOWN:

            if(GetWindowRect(hButton, &rect))
            {
                POINT p1 = {rect.left, rect.top};
                ScreenToClient(hWnd, &p1);
                SetWindowPos(hButton, NULL, p1.x, p1.y, rect.right - rect.left + 1, rect.bottom - rect.top + 1, SWP_SHOWWINDOW);

            }

            break;
        }

        break;
    case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
        GetCursorPos( &p );


        GetClientRect(hButton, &rect);
        SetWindowPos(hButton, NULL, p.x, p.y - 22, rect.right, rect.bottom, SWP_SHOWWINDOW);
        break;
    case WM_COMMAND:


        switch(LOWORD(wParam))
        {
        case 1:
            break;
        }

        break;

    case WM_CLOSE:
        DestroyWindow(hWnd);
        break;

    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;

    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
    }

    return 0;
}

int APIENTRY WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nShowCmd)
{

    WNDCLASSEXA wc;
    HWND hWnd;
    MSG msg;

    wc.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wc.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wc.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wc.hbrBackground = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(0,0,0));
    wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wc.hIconSm = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wc.hInstance = hInstance;
    wc.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    wc.lpszClassName = className;
    wc.lpszMenuName = "MENU!";
    wc.style = NULL;

    RegisterClassEx(&wc);

    hWnd = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_LAYERED, className, "hello", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, 0, 0, 500, 500, NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);
    SetLayeredWindowAttributes(hWnd, 0, 255, LWA_ALPHA);

    ShowWindow(hWnd, nShowCmd);
    UpdateWindow(hWnd);

    while(GetMessage(&msg, hWnd, 0, 0) > 0)
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);


    }


    return msg.wParam;
}
```

Comment: Buttons swallow some key presses. You can sub-class them and override `WM_GETDLGCODE` to change this behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that when you press the button, you focus on the current button, so your `WM_KEYDOWN` message is sent to that button.

So you need to subclass the button and handle the button's `WM_KEYDOWN` message.You can refer to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/subclassing-overview#subclassing-controls-using-comctl32dll-version-6).

Here is the modified sample:

```
#include <iostream>
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0501
#include <Windows.h>
#include <winuser.h>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <CommCtrl.h>
using namespace std;

const char* className = "MyCLASSNAME!";
HWND hWnd;
HWND hButton;
RECT rect;
POINT p = { 0, 0 };
WNDPROC ButtonOldProc;

LRESULT CALLBACK ButtonProcNew(HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam,LPARAM lParam, UINT_PTR uIdSubclass, DWORD_PTR dwRefData)
{
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_KEYDOWN:
        switch (wParam)
        {
        case VK_DOWN:

            if (GetWindowRect(hButton, &rect))
            {
                POINT p1 = { rect.left, rect.top };
                ScreenToClient(hWnd, &p1);
                SetWindowPos(hButton, NULL, p1.x, p1.y, rect.right - rect.left + 1, rect.bottom - rect.top + 1, SWP_SHOWWINDOW);
            }
            break;
        }
        break;
    default:
        return DefSubclassProc(hwnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
}
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (msg)
    {
    case WM_CREATE:

        hButton = CreateWindow(TEXT("BUTTON"), TEXT("1"), WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | BS_DEFPUSHBUTTON, 8, 41, 50, 50, hWnd, (HMENU)1, NULL, NULL);
        SetWindowSubclass(hButton, ButtonProcNew, 0, 0);
        break;

    case WM_KEYDOWN:
        switch (wParam)
        {
        case VK_DOWN:

            if (GetWindowRect(hButton, &rect))
            {
                POINT p1 = { rect.left, rect.top };
                ScreenToClient(hWnd, &p1);
                SetWindowPos(hButton, NULL, p1.x, p1.y, rect.right - rect.left + 1, rect.bottom - rect.top + 1, SWP_SHOWWINDOW);
            }
            break;
        }

        break;
    case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
        GetCursorPos(&p);
        GetClientRect(hButton, &rect);
        SetWindowPos(hButton, NULL, p.x, p.y - 22, rect.right, rect.bottom, SWP_SHOWWINDOW);
        break;
    case WM_COMMAND:
        switch (LOWORD(wParam))
        {
        case 1:
            break;
        }
        break;
    case WM_CLOSE:
        DestroyWindow(hWnd);
        break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
    }

    return 0;
}

int APIENTRY WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nShowCmd)
{

    WNDCLASSEXA wc;
    MSG msg;
    wc.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wc.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wc.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wc.hbrBackground = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(0, 0, 0));
    wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wc.hIconSm = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wc.hInstance = hInstance;
    wc.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    wc.lpszClassName = className;
    wc.lpszMenuName = "MENU!";
    wc.style = NULL;
    RegisterClassEx(&wc);
    hWnd = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_LAYERED, className, "hello", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, 0, 0, 500, 500, NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);
    SetLayeredWindowAttributes(hWnd, 0, 255, LWA_ALPHA);
    ShowWindow(hWnd, nShowCmd);
    UpdateWindow(hWnd);

    while (GetMessage(&msg, hWnd, 0, 0) > 0)
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
    return msg.wParam;
}
```

**Note:You need to link Comctl32.lib**

And it works for me:

[image]

Comment: As your compiler told you already, not all control paths in your button procedure return a value. Besides, we've had proper tools for [subclassing controls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/subclassing-overview#subclassing-controls-using-comctl32dll-version-6) for more than a decade now.

Comment: Hi @Astoach167, if this answer did help to you, please feel free to mark it to help people with the same issue, and let me know if you have any problem.Thanks.